# Sphinx documentation and autodoc-skip-member

Tags: django, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, sphinx-apidoc

I'm building my sphinx doc for a django project the following way:

```
sphinx-apidoc app -o docs/source/app --force
```

Now it includes all of the South migrations which I don't want to have in my documentation. I now tried to exclude them the following way:

```
conf.py:
    def skip_migrations(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
        return skip or (what == 'module' and name.find('Migration') != -1)\ 
               or str(obj).find('migrations') != -1

    def setup(app):
       app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', skip_migrations)
```

Now they aren't documented anymore, but are still listed under modules. How can I exclude them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may exclude the rst files created for the migrations by adding them to the exclude_pattern in your conf.py file:

```
exclude_patterns = ["**/*.migrations.rst",]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just avoid generating the .rst files with `sphinx-apidoc` in the first place:

```
sphinx-apidoc app -o docs/source/app --force */migrations/*
```

Patterns added after the module name are understood as excluded paths.

Comment: For those that come after me: The `--force` needs to be before the `-o` or else this command will fail. As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4771) it has something to do with argparse.